# Как выполнять task в отдельном потоке?

Tags: c#, .net, tpl

Есть метод, который читает журнал событий:

```
public List<LogPage> Read()
    {
        Task<List<LogPage>> task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            //здесь читаем
        });
        task.Wait();
        return task.Result;
    }
```

Вот так я его запускаю:

```
void LoadJournal_Execute(object paramete)
    {
        Log log = new Log();
        var events = log.Read();
    }
```

Как выполнять эту задачу в отдельном потоке? Чтобы GUI не зависало?
Версия .Net - 4.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы и так выполняете работу в другом потоке, просто вот тут

```
    task.Wait();
    return task.Result;
```

вы заставляете текущий поток ждать конца выполнения. Чтобы сделать задачу асинхронной, вам не надо ждать окончания таска. Как пример

```
public Task<List<LogPage>> ReadAsync()
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
            //здесь читаем
    }); 
}
```

и вызов

```
async void LoadJournal_Execute(object paramete)
{
    Log log = new Log();
    var events = await log.ReadAsync();
}
```

Но имейте ввиду, что код, который вызывает `LoadJournal_Execute` не узнает, когда метод завершит работу. Если надо, чтобы вызывающий код знал, когда работа завершится, то `LoadJournal_Execute` также должен вернуть таск.

```
async Task LoadJournal_Execute(object paramete)
{
    Log log = new Log();
    var events = await log.ReadAsync();
}
```

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, то в .NET 4 (что у автора) из коробки нету async/await. Нужно дополнительно устанавливать [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо, таких подробностей я уже не просто не помню :)

Comment: @tym32167: а как тогда async Task LoadJournal_Execute(object paramete) использовать для команд? для них ведь нужен тип void.
Оборачивать в обычный void?

Comment: @tym32167 все заработало! спасибо большое! просто изменил task на void. Спасибо большое!

Comment: @UporotayaPanda если мой ответ вам реально помог решить проблему, отметье его галочкой

Comment: @EvgeniyZ а Microsoft.Bcl.Async работает на win xp?

Comment: @UporotayaPanda Вообще, Win XP уже давно пора положить на полку истории, я раньше тоже разрабатывал приложение с поддержкой от WinXP, но со временем понял, что я теряю очень много и из за этого страдают сами пользователи. Теперь использую всегда самое новое. Но да, тут если только не специфичный заказчик (но такое редко). Ну а отвечая на ваш вопрос - то читайте поддерживаемые платформы `.NET Framework 4 (with KB2468871)` - то есть нужен как минимум .NET 4 и обновление KB2468871.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, как раз такой случай(
Заказчик хочет поддержку win xp, так как у них большое количество устройств на этой оси, и отказываться от них они планируют только после 20 года( Благодарю за помощь!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ с радостью использовал был версию .Net не ниже 4.5, но на xp максимально 4.0

Comment: @UporotayaPanda события и должны оставаться `async void`. Рекомендуется только каждый раз убеждаться, что они не выбросят исключений (иначе процесс может остановиться). Как вы это будете делать -- зависит от вас. В качестве железных трусов подойдет `try/catch` блок в каждом событии.