# Заполнение списка в отдельном потоке

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

После того как я получаю список с сервера, у меня этот список может быть в количестве от 0 до 15 элементов - не больше. Я создаю поток, в котором добавляю элементы в локальную базу и в локальный список. Проблема заключается в том , что когда я прохожусь циклом `foreach` по элементам, которые пришли с сервера, программа выбивает ошибку, что я выхожу за пределы списка, но при этом база и локальный список заполняется, в `Try Catch` ничего не попадает.
Метод в котором я запускаю поток

```
private void Start_Upload_Server(string ValueJobject)
        {
            try
            {
                // Загружаю сообщения с сервера 
                var TempList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<ChatModel>>(ValueJobject);
                Thread_UploadServer = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(GetLastMessage_onServer));
                Thread_UploadServer.Start(TempList);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                var s = ex;
            }
            
           
        } // Start_Upload_Server
```

Метод в котором я обрабатываю данные

```
 private async void GetLastMessage_onServer(object obj)
        {
            // Список с сервреа тут 15 элементов 
            var TempList = (ObservableCollection<ChatModel>)obj;
            try
            {
                // Бегу по списку 
                foreach (var item in TempList)
                {
                  
                    // Уточняем явялется ли сообщение шифрованным
                    var flag_Line_Correct = GetLineCorrect(item.Message);
                    if (flag_Line_Correct)
                        item.Message = Decript(item.Message);

                    // устанавливаю нужные мне параметры 
                    SetStartParametr_Message(item);

                    // Добавляю в локальную бд
                    await ChatDbService.AddMessage(item);

                    // Добавляю в локальный список 
                    MessageList.Add(item);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                var exception = ex.Message;
            }
            finally
            {

                Thread_UploadServer.Abort();
                Thread_UploadServer.Join();

            }
        } // GetAllMessage
```

Даже если внутри foreach не будет кода, и программа в пустую пробежится по списку она серавно выйдет за пределы списка.
Вот моя ошибка

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index'
```

Comment: В какой именно строке ошибка? / Поток максимум один запускается или может быть несколько? / Коллекция MessageList потокобезопасная? / ChatDbService потокобезопасный?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, я не могу сказать конкретно в какой строке проблема , даже если убрать код из цикла , и оставить его пустым (ничего не добавлять никуда) , то когда цикл завершает свою работу он пишет , что вышел за пределы массива. Грубо говоря если просто прокручивать цикл в потоке , то он вылетает , try catch не помогает.

Comment: Я вижу уже `async void` и мне больно становится. Всегда возвращайте `Task` и как-либо обрабатывайте результат - хотя-бы с помощью `await`. Почитайте про `Concurrent` коллекции. В конце-концов, нужна именно `ObservableCollection`? Попробуйте аналогичные коллекции, но потокобезопасные (вот пример - https://stackoverflow.com/q/3899940/13123688). Так же, хотелось-бы отметить создание потока (`new Thread`) - данная операция крайне тяжёлая. Вам точно без создания ещё одного потока не обойтись? Я вижу вполне решение через обычные `async await`

Comment: Так же, в качестве параметра почему вы передаёте `object`, а не какой-нибудь `IEnumerable<T>`? Операции `даун-` и `апкаста` не являются очень быстрыми. `ObservableCollection` ведь является дочерним классом `Collection`, поэтому вставка подходящей коллекции в качестве параметра здорово решит проблему (https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.collection-1?view=net-6.0 обратите внимание на наследование. Это поможет с выбором подходящей коллекции для параметра). Так же, для приведения коллекции к коллекции может помочь `ToList` или `ToArray`

Comment: Нужно пояснить в каких-то моментах? Не стесняйтесь обращаться (пользуйтесь `@*мой ник`, чтобы тегнуть меня)

Comment: @Frehzy, да мне нужен именно ObserbleCollection, так же , когда я открываю страницу , я хочу что бы она заполнялась параллельно загрузки интерфейса . У меня приложение на xamarin когда я открываю страницу чата, я загружаю данные сначала с локальной базы, а потом иду на сервер за новыми , что бы сравнить локальные , все это весьма емкий процесс , и хотелось бы это делать отдельно от основного потока

Comment: @Frehzy, в коде выше , который я предоставил , я создаю ситуацию, когда у пользователя нет локальных данных , и  я прогрузив интерфейс , параллельно хочу наполнить список MessageList , который отображается на странице, если это делать при загрузке страницы , то страница открывается намного дольше

Comment: object нужен для запуска параметризированного потока

Comment: Вы так категорично настроены против других Observable коллекций. Почему? :) Хотите параллельной загрузки - во время load вашей ViewModel делайте нужный вам запрос асинхронно и ждите результат с помощью await. Что делает await - в кратце, сохраняет ваш контекст. Вам нужно только лишь вызвать ваш async метод, добавив к вызову `await` и как-либо обработать данную информацию. Помните о том, что метод НЕ должен выполняться в UI-потоке. Посмотрите вот это видео https://youtu.be/lh8cT6qI-nA - оно прояснит ситуацию с асинхронными методами

Comment: Ну вот и смотрите план действий - отказываетесь от создания потока (причины выше + статьи в интернете, почему это плохо) и, посмотрев видео, переходите на `async await`. Это также избавит вас от потребности передавать object

Comment: @Frehzy, возможно вы правы , буду пробывать, спасибо за информацию

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/822149/378277 Нашёл ещё вот такой хороший ответ, который может вам подойти

Comment: @Frehzy, спасибо большое за информацию , я убрал дополнительный поток который создавал и запускаю метод через async await , а ошибка не выпадала из за того что у меня было "async void", Task Не возвращался и соответственно ошибка не приходила